# Deprecation and other attributes of methods in Swift, how?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

In Objective-C I can do this

```
- (id)init __attribute__((unavailable("init is unavailable, use initWithFrame")));
```

to warn users that should not use that method for initialization of a class and I can add this other __attribute to deprecate a method

```
+(void)shareWithParams:(NSDictionary *)params
__attribute((deprecated("use shareWithPars: instead")));
```

Is that possible to do something like that in Swift?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Swift has an `available` attribute that you can use for this. It's available arguments include

- introduced
- deprecated
- obsoleted
- message
- renamed.

Or for the example you gave:

```
@available(*, unavailable, message: "init is unavailable, use initWithFrame")
init() {

}

@available(*, deprecated, message: "use shareWithPars: instead")
class func shareWithParams(params: NSDictionary) {

}
```

For more information on these attributes, check out the Attributes section in [The Swift Programming Language](https://itun.es/us/k5SW7.l). (currently page 627)

Comment: Link to the HTML version of the Swift Programming Language: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html

Comment: Unfortunately, `@available` doesn't add anything to the generated Obj-C header for Swift code used by Obj-C. Is there any way to get Swift methods marked `__attribute__((unavailable()))` to obj-c? `@nonobjc` doesn't always work, the goal is to mark inherited methods unavailable.

Comment: Is it possible to just deprecate the default implementation in a protocol?

Answer (score 11):

For Swift 3 and Swift 4, instead of using the `=` sign to set the message, you have to use the `:` sign. For example:

```
@available(*, deprecated, message: "Use EndPointModel class instead")
class BaseModel {

}
```