# Swift - how to deprecate a function in SPM library

Tags: swift, versioning, swift-package-manager, deprecation-warning

We are maintaining a private SPM library, and I want to introduce a function that should be use instead of an existing function. The end result should be some kind of **deprecation**.

So far I found that functions can be deprecated relative to the OS versions, But I need to deprecate it relative to the Library version.

For example:

```swift
//how do I deprecate this function as of version `1.1.0` of my library?
func oldFunc() {
    ...
}

//It will be awesome if I could also mention that this function is the newer alternative to `oldFunc`
func newFunc() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deprecation and other attributes of methods in Swift, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346164/deprecation-and-other-attributes-of-methods-in-swift-how)

Comment: Yes that helps, but not entirely, because there is no versioning for library

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the something like this:

```
@available(*, deprecated, renamed: "newFunction")
func sampleFunction() { }
```

Comment: Thanks! You did answer the important part of the question. Also, is it possible to define obsolete version (relative to the library versions)?
I've found this `@available(iOS, obsoleted: 11.0)` but it only works with OS versions.

Comment: I am also unsure how to add the library version. In my case, I am just doing this: @available(swift, message: "Introduced in PodName v2.0").

Comment: According to https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html, for the `available` attribute it states: 

_Apply this attribute to indicate a declaration’s life cycle relative to certain Swift language versions or certain platforms and operating system versions._

Unfortunately no mention of library or app version.